# Insert and Delete error Gridview ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am using SQL command to insert and delete into the grid but getting following errors while executing.

Error   1   Use of unassigned local variable 'cmd'  (This is at INSERT INTO Table(ID,Summary) values ('" + Convert)
Error   2   'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Text'
Error   3   'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'CommandName' and no extension method 'CommandName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   4   'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'CommandArgument' and no extension method 'CommandArgument' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Error   5   The name 'fillgrid' does not exist in the current context

The HTML part is correct . But I think I have not written the insert and delete function properly
This is the HTML code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title> </title>
    </head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server">New Task</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" placeHolder="Type  
            new task summary here, and click add" Width="353px">    
            </asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" OnClick="click_add" 
            Text="Add" style="margin-left: 54px" Width="67px" />
            <br />
        </div>

        <asp:GridView ID="grdStatus" runat="server" 
        OnRowCommand="grdStatus_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Done?">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbx" runat="server" 
                    Checked='<%#Eval("Done") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="label12" runat="server" 
                    Checked='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Summary">
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="label3" runat="server" 
                    Checked='<%#Eval("Summary") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Created On">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="label4" runat="server" 
                    Checked='<%#Eval("Date")%>' ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="dltButton" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png"   
                    CommandName="DeleteTask" Text="Delete" Width="30px" 
                    Height="30px" CommandArgument="<%#     
                    Container.DataItemIndex%>" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The c# code is this

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string connectionString =    
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Northwind"].ConnectionString;
        string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            adapter.Fill(ds, "Table");

            grdStatus.DataSource = ds;
            grdStatus.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void click_add(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string connectionString =   
  WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Northwind"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO 
                             Table(ID,Summary) values ('" +  
            convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["label2"].Value.ToString())   
            + "'" + textbox1.Text  + "'"  DateTime.Text+ "'", con);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();


    }

    protected void grdStatus_RowCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.CommandName == "DeleteTask")
        {
            string connectionString =    
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Northwind"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            string query = "delete from Table where id=" + 
            e.CommandArgument + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            fillgrid();
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: `"but getting errors in implementation"` - Such as?

Comment: Start with putting commas between the values in the Insert command.

Comment: Provide us the error messages to give us ability to help you

Comment: 1.Use of unassigned local variable 'cmd' (This is at INSERT INTO Table )
2. 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Text' 
3.'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'CommandName' and no extension method 'CommandName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found 
4.'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'CommandArgument' and no extension method 
5. The name 'fillgrid' does not exist in the current context